# rails has_many - too many queries

Tags: ruby-on-rails, has-many

I have 4 models, Message, Group, User, Membership

```
class Group < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :memberships
  has_many :users, :through => :memberships
  has_many :groups_messages
  has_many :messages, :through => :groups_messages, :order => "created_at desc"

  named_scope :with_memberships, :include => :memberships

end

class Membership < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
  belongs_to :group
end

class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :memberships
  has_many :groups, :through => :memberships
end

class Message < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_and_belongs_to_many :recipients, :class_name => "User"
  has_many :groups_messages
  has_many :groups, :through => :groups_messages

  def accessible
   self.groups.with_memberships.map(&:user_ids).include?(User.current.id)
  end

end
```

Message can be posted to a Group, and if current User is a member of the group, he has a right to read it.

I am trying to check whether user is a member of the group with Message.accessible, but it produces one query to much:

```
 Group Load (0.1ms)   SELECT `groups`.* FROM `groups` INNER JOIN `groups_messages` ON `groups`.id = `groups_messages`.group_id WHERE ((`groups_messages`.message_id = 381)) AND ((`groups_messages`.message_id = 381)) 
 Membership Load (0.1ms)   SELECT `memberships`.* FROM `memberships` WHERE (`memberships`.group_id = 1) 
 User Load (0.1ms)   SELECT `users`.id FROM `users` INNER JOIN `memberships` ON `users`.id = `memberships`.user_id WHERE ((`memberships`.group_id = 1))
```

I don't need User Load query - user_id is contained in Membership, so last query is useless.

I tried changing accessible method to

```
 def accessible
   self.groups.with_memberships.exists?(:user_id=>User.current.id)
 end
```

But then it tries to use user_id in Group Load query and fails of course.
How can i get rid of the last query?
Rails 2.3.2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

after understanding rails better, i realized that it was happening because of **map(&:user_ids)** in

```
def accessible
  self.groups.with_memberships.map(&:user_ids).include?(User.current.id)
end
```

this behaviour was absolutely normal, my mistake was that i expected it to behave like **groups.membership_user_ids**, and it was behaving as **groups.user_ids**

fixed by changing to

```
def accessible
 Membership.exists?(["user_id=? and group_id in (?)",User.current.id,self.group_ids])
end
```

actually the part **include?(User.current.id)** wasn't even working for some reason.

Answer (score 0):

I think that query on users is caused by the call to `User.current.id`. Can you try passing in a parameter to the accessible method?

```
def accessible_to( user )
  self.groups.with_memberships.map(&:user_ids).include?(user.id)
end
```

I suppose this will be called from a controller, where current_user is (by convention) set, so in some controller action you'd do something like:

```
@message.accessible_to(current_user)
```

Comment: unfortunately, it's not the case. User.current.id is set way before(but I tried changing it just in case - didn't work).
Please notice that the useless query loads users which have group memberships. In provided case, Message belongs to Group with id=1, so it loads users which are members of Group with id=1.

Comment: Good point. What if you ask the user for their messages, instead of the messages that are accessible to a user: current_user.groups.messages